# Controller as root

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**What I want to achieve**

I have a controller, named "search", and I want this to work as the root of my application. So instead of having to input `www.mydomain.com/search/32` to get id 32 and `www.mydomain.com/search` to get my landing page, I want the urls to be `www.mydomain.com/32` and `www.mydomain.com`.

**What I have so far**

By adding `get ':id' => 'search#show', :as => :root` I manage to achieve `www.mydomain.com/32`, but then I can't add `root 'search#index'` since I can't have two routes with root.

Obviously there's a proper way to do this, so appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do it as follows

```
get ':id' => 'search#show'
root to: 'search#index'
```

If you remove the `as: "root"` from the show, it'll work. It's breaking, because you can't use the same prefix twice. If you need a prefix, just rename it to a different word.